# How do I uninstall older versions of GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, uninstallation, osx-elcapitan, haskell-platform

I installed Haskell Platform 7.10.3 on my mac and when it finished it said that it had detected older versions of GHC and to uninstall them, but how do I do that?

I'm using a macbook air with OS X 10.11.3.

Comment: I think this is some sort of bug. I installed GHC on a fresh machine and it gave me the same message.

Comment: I would suggest you install *stack* instead

Comment: Why are they down-voting my question is it bad? @Mika'il Thanks

Comment: @user32073 this question is off-topic on StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on https://superuser.com. I am voting to migrate it there.

Comment: I think it's borderline (maybe the hardest task in Haskell is setting it up) - but it's really only one vote - no big deal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can uninstall prior platforms by running

`uninstall-hs` from the command line.

You'll get an output like:

```
-- Versions found on this system
7.10.3
-- To remove a version and all earlier: uninstall-hs thru VERSION
-- To remove only a single version:     uninstall-hs only VERSION
```

And you can proceed from there...

Answer (score 1):

For removing a GHC version x.y.z, one can also use `ghcup rm x.y.z`.

Without version number `ghcup rm` lists the installed versions and asks which one to remove.