# How to manage multiple haskell installations on macOS?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I have on my computer (macOS High Sierra) multiple installations of the standard (Glasgow) Haskell compiler. The oldest one (as far as I can remember) is a [minimal installation](https://www.haskell.org/downloads#minimal), while I obtained the most recent version form the "[Platform](https://www.haskell.org/downloads#platform)" installer, something like five or six months ago. I'm trying to get rid of the whole ecosystem (ghc, stack, cabal, and friends), mostly because I don't know what tools I will be using in the case I'll plan to get back using the language.

So my questions are:

1. **Where** does the minimal/"Platform" installer installs Haskell and all related stuff?
2. **How** can one remove the whole Haskell language and all its components mentioned above (in the case of a "Platform" install, and even in the case of a minimal installation)?

EDIT: I've just remembered of the `uninstall-hs` command (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034915/how-do-i-uninstall-older-versions-of-ghc)), should I run this instead of removing files manually?

Comment: Do not worry about super user, as your question _directly involves tools used primarily for programming_. That is why I have edited that part out of your post.

Comment: Typically you can perform a "virtual environment" (like in Python), etc. with `haskell-stack`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have come up with a solution and I'll answer the latter question first:

- All the details I was looking for (what effectively is installed after launching the [minimal](https://www.haskell.org/downloads#minimal) / "[Platform](https://www.haskell.org/downloads#platform)" installer, and, most importantly, **where** these guys were placed) can be found in the documentation welcome file at `/Library/Haskell/Doc/Start.html`. More precisely:

  > On Mac OS X, the Haskell Platform is installed in two major pieces: GHC and Haskell Platform. They are installed respectively in: `/Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework` and `/Library/Haskell`. Executables are symlinked in `/usr/local/bin` [...].

  There are also another two or three directories in the home folder, namely `~/.ghc` and `~/.stack`.
- As said in the OP, the script `uninstall-hs` done its work, showing a (at least I hope so) comprehensive list of all the files that constitutes the Haskell "sdk" actually installed.

Feel free to post your answers, I hope this post will be useful to the community.